# How to apply rules to only certain elements in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this loop in react:

```
<div>
   {this.state.dealersDeck.map(function(card, index){
      return <div className="cardFormatDH" key={ index }> {card.rankKey}{card.suit} </div>;
   }, this)}
</div>
```

This goes through an array of objects and then renders them on screen. This is all good except I would like to format it so I only display the contents at certain points. i.e. I'm creating blackjack and I don't want the dealers second card to be visible until the end.

I may have to show more code but was wondering if `map` had some sort of attribute that I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use basic If...Else statements inside map function as well. Moreover you can write more business logic also to add more functionality.

```
var cardsHTML = this.state.dealersDeck.map(function(card, index){

    if(condition...1){
        return <div className="cardFormatDH" key={ index }> {card.rankKey}{card.suit} </div>
    }

    if(condition...2){
        return <div></div>
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this:

`if (this.state.dealersDeck[1]){
              return <div className="cardFormatDH" key={ index }> {'-'}{'-'} </div>;
            }
            else{
              return <div className="cardFormatDH" key={ index }> {card.rankKey}{card.suit} </div>;
            }`
but it changes all the cards to the new style

Answer (score 1):

You could add a boolean prop to each card and render based on that:

```
<div>
   {this.state.dealersDeck.map(function(card, index){
      return { card.display &&
          <div className="cardFormatDH" key={ index }>{card.rankKey} {card.suit} </div> 
      }
   }, this)}
</div>
```

Comment: but I wont know which card it is as it will be different every time